# Not receiving ethers after selling the tokens

Tags: transactions

I have successfully sold my tokens to the Smart Contract today. However, I did not receive the ethers from the sale.

Here's the txn number: 0x9ae532d08430a9aa5108c9feffbc62b6f31e5078e93ed6016cf232688e46c8aa

Not sure what's wrong, but this is the first time it happened. Appreciate anyone's help on this.

Comment: Have you called `withdraw()`?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the contract, you have to press Withdraw button in Gripcoin to get your ether.